# How can I make a conditional statement to check whether the "inputted" number is an integer or is in the decimal form in python?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I am trying to make a calculator in **python** where you can add, subtract, multiply, divide, find the exponential, find the nth root of x and also for factorial of a number.

While trying to finish the calculator I realized there was a problem with calculating the factorial of a number with decimal as there is not thing called factorial of a number with a decimal.

Here is the code for factorial that I used.

```
a = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
ab = 1
ac = a
if a > 1:
    while a > 1:
         ab = ab*a
         a = a - 1
         print (ac,"factorial is",ab)
elif a == 0:
    print("0 factorial is 1")
else:
    print("There is no negetive factorial")
```

I tried to search for any code that could work out, but I still couldn't find any code for that.

I also tried to edit the above code like this.

```
a = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
ab = 1
ac = a
if not(a/1):
    print("there is no factorial of number with decimal")
else:
    if a > 1:
        while a > 1:
             ab = ab*a
             a = a - 1
             print (ac,"factorial is",ab)
    elif a == 0:
        print("0 factorial is 1")
    else:
        print("There is no negetive factorial")
```

Still, It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Not the answer you're after, but the gamma function is defined for real numbers and is very closely related

Comment: A true online scientific calculator would not do your process. For any real `x`, the operation `x!` should give `Γ(x+1)` (gamma function). So, instead of this, why don't you use `math.gamma(a+1)`

Comment: You can use the [modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), e.g. `if a % 1 > 0: print("there is no factorial of number with decimal")`

Comment: Yes, in this question I have found the way to check if the inputted integer is an integer or    not.

Answer (score 0):

A true online scientific calculator would not do your process. For any real `x`, the operation `x!` should give `Γ(x+1)` (gamma function). So, instead of this, why don't you use `math.gamma(a+1)`.

By doing this you would get the factorial for `a`, given that `a` is an integer.

Here is an example:

```
import math

a = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
print(math.gamma(a+1))
```

Here is a more detailed understanding of [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). The gamma function can be used to extend the factorial function to all complex numbers, and this is one of its primary uses.

This would be a simpler and more realistic way to handle factorial operations on a calculator. It's an alternative method to achieve a similar ultimate goal as yours.

Comment: this actually works for making the whole factorial code smaller. But what I actually asked was of making a conditional statement to check whether the inputted number is a decimal or not. But anyway, I got an answer from another question. Also, would I face any problems if I don't export 'math'?

Answer (score -2):

if I understood you well, i tried this :

```
a = float(input("Enter the first number: "))
ab = 1
ac = a
if int(a) > 0:
    while a > 1:
        ab = int(ab*a)
        a = int(a) - 1
    print (int(ac),"factorial is",int(ab))
elif int(a) == 0:
    print("0 factorial is 1")
else:
    print("There is no negetive factorial")
```

Comment: `int(a) > 0` for any a >= 1, whether or not its fractional part is zero, which is what OP cares about.

Comment: but if a user enters a number like 0.25 he will see the elif message

Comment: it is int(a) == 0

Comment: My bad, I hadn't refreshed to get the edit. But entering (for example) 2.25 will try to calculate a factorial, whereas OP wants to print "there is no factorial of number with decimal" in that scenario.

Comment: You're right, but he can change the code if he wants such logic I gave.